# Counting number of overlayed points in line feature using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, overlapping-features

I created a polyline representing a road using GPS points.

Then I have another set of data of random GPS co-ordinates which i have to overlay on that polyline (Road).

I am trying to calculate how many random points occur in each 1 km section of that line(road).

Can anybody give me a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

1. split your polyline using split tool in editor .if your unit is based on meters. type 1000 meters .
2. use spatial joint to join polyline with points . target feature is your polyline and Join feature is your point layer.  in join operation combobox, select "JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY"
3. open attribute table of the result . TARGET_FID field show you how many points occure in each section .for example in this field you have three "1" that means you have three points in that section.
   [image]